# Pygame "Asteroids" Style Screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to design a game with screen transfer mechanics similar to Asteroids. I want it so that if you move to the edge of the screen, you appear on the other end. Here is a test code so far. The idea is to move too far right and reappear on the left. I do appear on the left, but only after I lift up on the right key.

if position_x >= 1200:
            position_x = 0

Comment: You should probably show us the rest of your code.  If it's being affected by the keypress, you need to show the code that deals with key events.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should post some of your code so we know how you set position_x and how you use it, but what I can say that might help is to use modulo instead of direct resetting. So for example, when you're updating position_x - `position_x = (position_x + speed) % 1200`